# How can I safely use action delegate when delegate's target removed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I usually use delegate for callback. For example I declare Action delegate in manager in unity script and I register delegate when  OnEnable called and unsubscribe when OnDisable called in my Monobehaviuor derived script. But I knew maybe it can be dangerous if I resister and unresister at wrong time. For example if object deleted by someone. delegate target will be null. Then unwanted delegate callback can be. 
So I want to check delegate's target is null when delegate excute and I want to remove it and I want to resister delegate uniquely when same delegate called in same script. How can I use it safely? here is my source example.

manager class

```
    public class TestManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Action TestDelegate;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            if(null != TestDelegate)
            {  
                TestDelegate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

object class

```
public class WindosTest : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    TestManager _manager;   

    private void Awake()
    {   
        _manager.TestDelegate += Test;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            GameObject.DestroyImmediate(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Test()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is using DestroyImmediate instead of Destroy. The main difference between those two is that Destroy calls for proper deconstruction of an object, which means it will recieve its OnDisable() callback befrore being destroyed (so it has a chance to unsubscribe from delegates).

Normally (not in editor) its better to call Destroy() instead of DestroyImmediate() because of safety.

If you call Destroy(), you'll get normal OnDisable callback which means you can do:

```
void OnEnable()
{   
    _manager.TestDelegate += Test;
}
void OnDisable()
{   
    _manager.TestDelegate -= Test;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will change destroyImmediate to destroy. But what I want is remove delegate that target is null. When delegate's target is null, I don't want to call.

Comment: you are already doing that with   if(null != TestDelegate)       {  TestDelegate();  }

Comment: edited the answer to include code to unsubscribe on object destruction

Answer (score 0):

you are already doing it, unless i have misunderstood the question

If you want to make it shorter jut do it as follows, but your code hsould work since you are checking for null already

```
TestDelegate?.Invoke();
```

Comment: Your null check more simple. Thank you for your answer.  But what I want is remove delegate that target is null. When delegate's target is null, I don't want to call

Comment: Sorry,  but i have no idea what you asking.What does remove delegate that target is null? Not sure what that mens.